# Aggregate field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, aggregate

I have question about aggregate values from attribute table.

I have something like this:

[image]

and I'd like want to get something like this:

[image]

I use aggregate tool but without good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way of doing it in one operation in QGIS, but one way to do it is to use `aggregate_unique` expression then use the dissolve tool.

First create a new field and use the following expression:
`concatenate_unique("wtg", group_by:= "id", concatenator:=',')`

Then use the dissolve tool and use the newly created concatenated field as the dissolve field. Note this assumes the layer has geometry associated with it, as I don't think either the core dissolve tool or GDAL dissolve tools work on layers with no geometry.

Comment: fulus89 many many thanks. Your expression work like charm. After create new field I just use delete duplicates by attribute tools to get unique Id records.